# No funciona programación de Cron en Magento

Tags: crontab, magento-1.9

Tengo configurado un `Magento` en mi `Centos` y agregué un módulo con una tarea de `cron` que se debe ejecutar cada 6 horas, pero se  ejecuta cada 10 minutos, tengo instalado el plugin `Aoe_Scheduler` y la carpeta de `magento` tiene como propietario al usuario 'centos' y edite el crontab del usuario `apache` para que la tarea se programara pero no lo hace cada 6 horas sino cada 10 minutos.

Esta es mi tarea:

```
  <crontab>
    <jobs>
      <fatima_syncdb_task>
        <schedule>
          <cron_expr>0 */6 * * *</cron_expr>
        </schedule>
        <run>
          <model>syncdb/syncdb::syncdbcrontask</model>
        </run>
      </fatima_syncdb_task>
    </jobs>
  </crontab>
```

`crontab` del usuario centos:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /var/www/html/cron.sh
```

`crontab` del usuario apache:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /var/www/html/cron.sh
```

Ya intenté limpiar caché de`Magento` y reiniciar `apache` pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar un `task` cada 6 horas podrías hacer algo como esto:

`Crontab` del usuario `centos`:

> 0 */6 * * * /usr/bin/sh /var/www/html/cron.sh

`Crontab` del usuario `apache`

> 0 */6 * * * /usr/bin/sh /var/www/html/cron.sh

`Crontab` tiene el siguiente formato:

> 0 minutos * /6 horas * día * mes * día del a semana

Donde `/` significa el step de cada valor asignado. Puesdes revisar está página que es muy útil para sacar `crontab` personalizados.

[http://crontab.guru/](http://crontab.guru/every-6-hours)

Comment: Gracias, pero eso no me funciona ya que ejecuta el cron cada 6 horas, eso quiere decir que ejecutará todas las tareas de magento en ese lapso. Actualmente tengo ejecutando cada 5 minutos, pero hay una tarea que se debe ejecutar cada 6 horas y no lo está haciendo, sino a cada hora.

Comment: Si es para una tarea especifica puedes usar crontab -e y se abre un archivo el cual debes modificar pegando lo de arriba en ese archivo en las últimas líneas, eso debería de correr tu programa cada 6 horas, eso en teoría debería de funcionar, quedo atento.

Comment: La tomé como válida ya que no logré hacer que el plugin Aoe_Scheduler ejecutara la tarea a dicho periodo.

Comment: Entonces no es tan válida finalmente la respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Esto debería funcionar

```
<crontab>
<jobs>
  <fatima_syncdb_task>
    <schedule>
      <cron_expr>0 0,6,12,18 * * *</cron_expr>
    </schedule>
    <run>
      <model>syncdb/syncdb::syncdbcrontask</model>
    </run>
  </fatima_syncdb_task>
</jobs>
```

Esto haría que tu método syncdbcrontask se ejecutara a las 12 de la noche, a las 6 de la mañana, a las 12 del medio día, a las 6 de la tarde y vuelta a empezar. Es decir, cada 6 horas.

Comment: Y que hace ese código?

Comment: Postear solo código se considera de baja calidad, edítala y añade una explicación